# Missing keys in JSON format

Tags: android, json, exception

I am trying to parse a JSON string in Android which is dynamical. It is a very simple JSON structure. Similar to the following:

```
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5
}
```

But sometimes I don't get some keys. For example, the key "b" could be missing. Then my code generates a JSONParser Exception. And the further JSON string could not parsed.

So is there any way to ignore missing keys?  I tried `optString();` but that only works in String case, what about JSONObject and JSONArray? `optJSONArray()` and `optJSONObject()` don't work.

Any idea or solution?

Comment: "optJSONArray() and optJSONObject() does not work" - what exactly doesn't work? Please be more specific.

Comment: if i tried to get value of corresponding JSONObject and JSONParser from missing keys , then getJSONArray("key") and getJSONObject("key") return exception . i used  optJSONArray("key") and optJSONObject("key")   but problem is still persistent

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to use 
[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)!

You simply create a plain old java object (POJO) representing the data you want and let GSON do the rest. If the value doesn't exist in the json string, it'll be set to the "default" for that type (usally null, but is 0 for ints, false for booleans etc...)

To include in your Android Studio project:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Also take a look at [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson), with particular attention to the "Object Examples" heading for how to use GSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can find dynamic key using belo

```
    String jsonString = "{ \"a\": 1, \"b\": 2, \"c\": 3, \"d\": 4, \"e\": 5 }";



try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject issueObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        Iterator iterator = issueObj.keys();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)iterator.next();

            Integer value = (Integer) issueObj.get(key);
            Log.d(TAG,"value: "+value);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or you can use GSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert that JSONObject to a Map using GSON, like the following:

```
        String json1 = "{\n" +
                "    \"a\": 1,\n" +
                "    \"b\": 2,\n" +
                "    \"c\": 3,\n" +
                "    \"d\": 4,\n" +
                "    \"e\": 5\n" +
                "}";
        Gson gson1 = new Gson();
        Type type1 = new TypeToken<Map<String, Integer>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, Integer> myMap1 = gson1.fromJson(json1, type1);
```

In your **build.gradle** file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```